# C# - Exclude class with 'Windows code' when on OSX

Tags: c#, windows, macos, port

I've been unable to find an answer, after multiple queries on google. I have made a program on my windows PC. It has features that only work on Windows, e.g. SpeechRecognition and Global hotkeys.

Currently I am trying to get the program to work on my MacBook. However due to missing namespaces on OSX I am unable to port it with exactly the same code.

The solution I thought of is to put all the 'Windows code' into a separate class and only load this class into the project if the OS is Windows. However this still results in errors in the coding environment.

I was wondering if it is possible to get this working. If the (missing namespace)-errors can somehow be suppressed, the code would still work.

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: You can build an external assembly with the windows code(a .dll). You can check your OS type on runtime...if it's a windows OS, you can load that assembly using `Reflection`

Comment: How about wrapping the code in `#if !NETSTANDARD2.0` (with the [correct version number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library))

Comment: @stuartd Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks for your answer! It would work but I wouldn't be able to edit the code quickly.